# avi encoded to streaming mp4 or webmnot playing in html5 player

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264, mp4

[EDIT]

I'm trying to get ffmpeg to encode various AVI files to mp4 for streaming purposes

I use this nodejs to start FFMPEG.

When I try this (webm) (some settings are wrapped by the node module but produce the default FFMPEG command) with this command:

```
        .withVideoCodec('libvpx')
        .addOptions(['-bf 8','-bt 240k','-preset fast','-strict -2','-b:v 320K','-bufsize 62000', '-maxrate 620k','-movflags +empty_moov','-y'])
        .withAudioBitrate('192k')
        .withAudioCodec('libvorbis')
        .toFormat('webm')
```

The video get's streamed properly to the client but the duration isn't passed on. So the video has  a duration of 'infinite'.

So I tried to encode with H264. Which also works (I see the duration being set in the client) but no picture sadly.

For H264 I use:

```
   .addOptions(['-y','-vcodec libx264','-bf 8','-bt 240k','-preset fast','-strict -2','-b:v 320K','-bufsize 62000', '-maxrate 620k','-acodec aac','-ab 128k','-movflags +empty_moov'])
   .toFormat('mp4')
```

I get this log :

[image]

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

The client just gives an undefined error.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue? You didn't describe what isn't working.

Comment: Please show the complete ffmpeg console output that results after you run your ffmpeg command.